# Bittorrent tracker request

Tags: get, request, bittorrent, tracker

Using a torrent file from

```
http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/
```

I am calculating its hash which matches with the hash on the page.

Then i make a request to the tracker. Like

```
http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?info_hash=9a81333c1b16e4a83c10f3052c1590aadf5e2e20
```

But i get

> d14:failure reason63:Requested download is not authorized for use with this tracker.e

According to the spec this should work?

[Tracker Spec](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentTrackerProtocol)
[General Spec](http://wiki.theory.org/BitTorrentSpecification)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You specified the info_hash in hex, rather than URL-encoding.  The bytes of the SHA-1 hash should be encoded directly, like this:

```
http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/file?info_hash=%9A%813%3C%1B%16%E4%A8%3C%10%F3%05%2C%15%90%AA%DF%5E.%20
```

Also, for the `announce` URL, some additional parameters like `peer_id` are usually required.

Comment: Thx, can you be more specific as to how you come up with the encoding? i assumed since there are no non-ascii chars in the hash i should not have to escape it. Did you encode the bytes from the sha-1?

Comment: Thank you, I have just noticed that i make your request to file not announce, if i change info to announce i get id not 20 bytes long error. should i make my request against file not announce?

Comment: "file" is for downloading the torrent file; I used that because it requires only the info_hash parameter.  For "announce", many more parameters are required; the error you are getting is because you are missing peer_id.  Here is a working announce URL for this torrent: http://torrent.ubuntu.com:6969/announce?info_hash=%9A%813%3C%1B%16%E4%A8%3C%10%F3%05%2C%15%90%AA%DF%5E.%20&peer_id=ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST&port=6881&uploaded=0&downloaded=0&left=727955456&event=started&numwant=100&no_peer_id=1&compact=1

Comment: Thanks url helped me a lot in putting togerher a working request.